# Css media query not loads with specific screen

Tags: html, css

I have to apply height for two different screen 1080px and 1000px.

I have added following media query:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:1080px){
    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1080px;
        float: left;
    }
    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:109px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-height:1000px){
    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
    }

    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:106px;
    }
}
```

When i switched to 1080px the issues remain's same, it call's the media query for 1000px.

http://ddslauncher.com/inventory-new/

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How you are testing the responsive behavior ?.

Comment: I am testing in with chrome, when i enter in fullscreen mode in chrome the issue rises

Comment: Your example works on my 1920x1080 screen, can you double check the resolution of the screen you are using?

Comment: @cfreear it show's vertical scroll, can you double check on 1920x1000px and 1920x1080px

Comment: I've just checked your CSS and the ordering of your media queries when using max-height is very important. If you inspect your wrapper element in chrome you will see that `@media only screen and (max-height:1000px){` IS being applied but then `@media only screen and (max-height:1080px){` is overriding it as it comes after. Having them the other way round (as in your question) should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

The media queries in your example are the other way round from your question. They are:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:1000px){

    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
    }

    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:106px;;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-height:1080px){
    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1080px;
        float: left;
    }

    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:109px;;
    }
}
```

(the issue here is that when the screen is below 100px in height both queries match and the second one is applied ass CSS 'cascades' down.)

instead of:

```
@media only screen and (max-height:1080px){

    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1080px;
        float: left;
    }

    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:109px;
    }
}


@media only screen and (max-height:1000px){
    #wrapper {
        width: 1884px;
        height: 1000px;
        float: left;
    }

    .filter-selection ul li
    {
        height:106px;
    }
}
```

Using this second example should fix your issue.

**EDIT** Apologies for the formatting issues, something is interfering with my SO edits.

Comment: don't use `!important` as that is not the issue here.

Comment: @marczking thanks, I had copied the code from OP's example, should have checked it closer. Edit approved.

Comment: I tried them it did for me. Maybe make a jsfiddle or codepen with your code?

Comment: @marczking can you please check it right now on my live server, and yes jsfiddle will help's... Thanks allot

Comment: It works for me, if it still doesn't for you, maybe define it like `@media only screen and (min-width: 1001px) and (max-height:1080px)`

Comment: Did you manage to get it working? If not what are you experiencing? 1080px height when below 1000px?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the percentage width instead of fixed. something like the following. Also it would be great if you can run the media query based on Viewport width not height.

```
@media only screen and (max-height:1080px){
#wrapper {
width: 100%;
height: 1080px;
float: left;
} 
}
```

Comment: I don't think the wrapper width is the issue, OP is seeing the height set to `1000px` when he's expecting `1080px`

Comment: @cfreear yes the issue is with height

Answer (score 0):

I saw yours stylesheet. in css u have "min-height". I suggest to change into max-height, and used "!important" adnotation.

Comment: remeber about order of "media" in css, first u must have this case with max:1080, then max:1000